# Pattern related to the exponents of the prime factorization of natural numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, factoring, prime-factorization

While doing recreational mathematics, I noticed a curious pattern related to the prime factorization of numbers. If you arrange this factorization for all the numbers up to a certain $N$, according to the table below,

[image]

One can add up all the exponents of each prime. By plotting the pairs (in the case of $N=100000$ in the image above) (2,99989), (3,49995), (5,24994), ... in a graph, it produces a curve that almost perfectly fits the equation $y=N/x$:

[image]
(Here is the graph in logarithmic scale for N=1000000 for primes up to 10000: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPTpa.png)

In the image above, the red dots are the plotted points/pairs and the blue curve is the said equation.

In this sense, the above facts can be more specifically stated as the following problem:

For any number $n$,
$$n=\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}p_i^{a_{n,i}}$$
Show that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{N}a_{i,k}\sim N/p_k$$
Where $p_k$ is the kth prime.

Is this true, and are there useful/interesting implications?

Comment: Hint: since every $p$th number is a multiple of $p$, every $p^2$th number is a multiple of $p^2$, etc., we have $\sum_{i=1}^N a_{i,k} = \lfloor \frac N{p_k} \rfloor + \lfloor \frac N{p_k^2} \rfloor + \lfloor \frac N{p_k^3} \rfloor + \cdots$.

Comment: If $floor(N/p_k)$ is the number of numbers divisible by $p_k$ between 1 and $N$, shouldn't every term with a $p_k^m$ be multiplied by $m$ because the respective exponent of numbers divisible by $p_k^m$ is $m$?

Comment: You're right, but I think your conjecture is wrong ($N/p_k$ is not what you got for *small* $p_k$). If you look at the contribution of including the coefficient of $m$, it barely makes a difference: it will make no difference for $p_k > \sqrt{N}$, and even for, e.g., $p_k\approx 200$, with your $N$ it would add only 2.5 to the predicted result. So your sums are almost exactly what you would get if you didn't count multiplicity, which will approach $N/p_k$ by Greg Martin's argument.

Comment: Actually, I checked Greg's expression and it works perfectly. From it, you can approximate the sum as the series of $N/p_k^i$ from $i=1$ to infinity. The result will be $N/(p_k-1)$, which is the correct expression and calculates all the values extremely accurately for all $p_k$. I didn't think about the -1 term in the denominator.

Comment: The reason Greg's equation works is because the number of numbers divisible by $p_k^i$ also counts the number of numbers divisible by all previous powers of $p_k$. The reasoning in my previous comment would only be true if each term were the number of numbers ONLY divisible by $p_k^i$

Comment: Yeah, I completely missed that everything divisible by $p_k^2$ gets double-counted - once from $N/p_k$, and again fro $N/p_k^2$. Sorry!